# Why isn't IDLE in the folder with the Python program?

Tags: python, installation

I am a complete beginner to programming. I downloaded Python 3.4.3. 64 bit for my Windows 10 OS. The download specified that it included IDLE. I opened Python with no issue, but IDLE was not in that folder. I searched for it on my C drive and it didn't match any file names.

Did it save somewhere else?

Comment: I think you have a file in the installed path named "pythonw.exe". It's IDE of python

Comment: First, thank you so much for trying to help me!!!!!!  I have that file in my python folder but I tried to open it and open the other python program, but it closed the original program. I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed IDLE correctly, it will appear in your menu with a folder for IDLE.  Look there.  If not, attempt to reinstall IDLE. It will not affect anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me!!! The problem is that IDLE isn't in its own folder. When I downloaded Python, IDLE was supposed to be in the folder with python. It wasn't. I tried to find a way to download just IDLE and I couldn't find it anywhere.